# Why didn't I get avios for every pound I spent using Amex British Airways

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, american-express, frequent-flier-miles

I've been using an American Express British Airways credit card. As it is advertised, it gives you one avios per pound you spend. However, I only got 29 avios after spending more than 100 pounds.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: How long has it been between the spending and checking your awarded miles?  You might need to check back after the next statement cycle.

Comment: OK I'll wait and see.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you spent the money on. From the [terms and conditions](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/executive-club/collecting-avios/credit-cards/uk):

> For the Credit Card, you will be awarded one Avios for virtually every £1 spent and charged per transaction. Avios are not earned on Balance Transfers, Cash Withdrawals, American Express Travellers Cheques purchases, Foreign Exchange, interest, any spending in excess of your credit limit, charges for returned payments, late payment or referral charges and American Express Credit Card finance charges. Written details available on request.

Comment: that's weird I think I didn't spend on those categories.